# How to use MIN() by date in a clause that uses SUM() for another date?

Tags: mysql, sql, min, having

I need to find all the clients that have their first order in 2017 and sum up their incomes in 2018. I have issue trying to do that in SQL clause.

In my table I have 3 clients, 2 of them first ordered in 2017-05-23, and 1 in 2016-06-23. So I want to filter out that one client that ordered in 2016. In a table I have fields: client, income, order_date.

This is what I have in MySQL:

```sql
select client as 'Clients first order in 2017',
       SUM(income) as 'Sum of income in 2018'  
from orders
where YEAR(order_date) = 2018
  and (select client, order_date
       from orders
       group by client
       having min(year(order_date)) = 2017)
order by client
```

I am expecting to get all the clients that first ordered in 2017 and sum up their incomes for 2018

Comment: Give some example datas.

Comment: Don't you get an error when running the code above?

Comment: Should a client with no order in 2018, but with a first order in 2017, be included in the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
Select client as 'Clients first order in 2017', 
        SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(order_date) = 2018 
                 THEN income 
                 ELSE 0 
            END) as 'Sum income in 2018'  
FROM orders
GROUP BY client
HAVING MIN (YEAR(order_date)) = 2017
order by client
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
SELECT 
client as 'Clients first order in 2017', 
SUM(income)  as 'Sum of income in 2018'
FROM orders 
WHERE client IN
(
    SELECT client 
    FROM orders 
    GROUP BY client
    HAVING MIN(YEAR(order_date)) = 2017
)
AND YEAR(order_date) = 2018
GROUP BY client
```

Comment: you are welcome. you can put an up vote if it really helped :)

Comment: I can't do that now as my reputation is too low. Your approach basically is the same as mine, but I have missed that "WHERE IN" part.

Comment: its ok anyway :)